# How to use filter in that case? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, methods, filter

Can some one help to write function which will filter my search results?
There is code in Sandobox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-snowflake-irbhf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchValue: "",
    songs: [],
    musicTabs: ["Random", "Bass", "Player", "Chords", "Guitar"],
    result: ""
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSelectChange = event => {
    this.setState(
      {
        result: event.target.value
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.result)
    );
  };

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
  };

  makeApiCall = async searchInput => {
    let api_url = `https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/.json?pattern=${searchInput}`;
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const songs = await response.json();
    this.setState({ songs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          name="text"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Wyszukaj..."
          onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
          value={this.state.SearchValue}
        />

        <Select
          optionValue={this.state.musicTabs}
          change={this.handleSelectChange}
          value={this.state.result}
        />

        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>

        {this.state.songs ? (
          <div>
            {this.state.songs.map((song, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="lists">
                <h1>
                  Artist: <span>{song.artist.name}</span>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                  Song title: <span>{song.title}</span>
                </h2>
                <ol>
                  <b>Available tabs:</b>
                  {song.tabTypes.map((tab, index) => (
                    <li key={index}> {song.tabTypes[index]} </li>
                  ))}
                </ol>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Something</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Select = props => {
  const { optionValue, change } = props;

  const valueMusicTabs = optionValue.map((musicTab, index) => {
    return (
      <option name={optionValue[index]} key={index}>
        {" "}
        {optionValue[index]}{" "}
      </option>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={change}>{valueMusicTabs}</select>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to search by input value and selected value. For example if I type any title or song name and choose Bass I want to render results with songs/artist which includes "Bass" in available tabs. If there will be selected "Random", then it should render all results. Please help me, I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: Do you want it like in the following [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-mountain-8gb6u)? It's a bit complicated because your tab identifiers are not matching the string from the select box. If the code is working for you, I can add an answer with some explanations and how you could improve the code.

Comment: Yes it's awesome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple ways to perform this operation. For example you can put filtered songs in state and then map them in render method or you can filter them in render method as I have written below.

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <input
      name="text"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Wyszukaj..."
      onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
      value={this.state.SearchValue}
    />

    <Select
      optionValue={this.state.musicTabs}
      change={this.handleSelectChange}
      value={this.state.result}
    />

    <br />
    <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>

    {this.state.songs ? (
      <div>
       //you can filter your songs here then map them
       //so whenever result or songs is changed this will 
        {this.state.songs.filter(s => this.state.result === 'Random' || s.tabTypes.includes(this.state.result.toUpperCase())).map((song, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="lists">
            <h1>
              Artist: <span>{song.artist.name}</span>
            </h1>
            <h2>
              Song title: <span>{song.title}</span>
            </h2>
            <ol>
              <b>Available tabs:</b>
              {song.tabTypes.map((tab, index) => (
                <li key={index}> {song.tabTypes[index]} </li>
              ))}
            </ol>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>Something</p>
    )}
  </div>
);}
```

And you probably need to update 'result' according to the value not the input name. You can set the value for the input like this:

```
<option value={value} name={name} key={index}>
```

Therefore while you show appropriate names to users, you can get the appropriate key for querying.

**Let me know if you got stuck somewhere. I think what I wrote above can give you and idea.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple filter method call to compare results based on the `this.state.result` selection chosen. It will not work completely for your case, as your dropdown selections do not match the strings that are returned in the json. If you wish to use this solution then some modifications to the filter will need to be made, for instance it works for `"PLAYER"`,`"CHORDS"`, and `"RANDOM"`, but will not work for `"TEXT_BASS_TAB"` or `"TEXT_GUITAR_TAB"` as it checks the literal string of `this.state.result`. Perhaps a key-value mapping where keys are your dropdown options and values are the json-equivalent could be a viable way to make this work. I also changed your songs value from const to just be let, but that was just for simplicity of testing. This should get you started on the solution that works best for you.

```
let songs = await response.json();
    if (this.state.result !== "Random" && this.state.result !== "") {
      songs = songs.filter(song =>
        song.tabTypes.includes(this.state.result.toUpperCase())
      );
    }
this.setState({ songs });
```